# How to add margins, padding, and stop text being all caps in a dynamically added toggle button?

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile

So I've created some toggle buttons dynamically that get added to a linear layout. I am able to successfully edit some of the stylings for the buttons, but for the attributes listed in the title, I have been unsuccessful in getting any change.

This is the function creating buttons using the name from my SQLite db.

```
void addFilterButtons(){
        Cursor cursor = my_db.readData();
        if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
 
        }else{
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                String name = cursor.getString(1);
                ToggleButton filter_button = new ToggleButton(getActivity());
                filter_button.setChecked(false);
                filter_button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.toggle_bg);
                filter_button.setTextAppearance(R.style.TBStyle);
                filter_button.setTextOn(name);
                filter_button.setTextOff(name);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                filter_button.setLayoutParams(lp);
                linear_layout.addView(filter_button, lp);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the styling for toggle button.

```
<style name="TBStyle" parent="android:Widget.Button.Toggle">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/toggle_bg</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginStart">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/toggle_txt</item>
    </style>
```

This is toggle_txt and toggle_bg drawables.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/white"/>
    <item android:color="@color/blue"/>
</selector>
```

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/round_btn_gray"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/round_btn_white"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this, but the easiest-  put the view you want in an XML file.  Then inflate the XML file.  Then you don't have to do any of the tedious settings in code.